# Haskell program simple game

Tags: function, haskell

I am very new in haskell-programming. I try to program a simple dice-game, but I don't know to do it in haskell.

```
 suc :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Int -> (Int,Int,Int) -> Bool

 suc  (a₁,a₂,a₃) c (d₁,d₂,d₃)
```

I want to consider each difference dᵢ - aᵢ (but not if aᵢ > dᵢ)  and return False if (d1-a1)+(d2-a2)+(d3-a3) are  larger than c.  (if aᵢ > dᵢ then I sum up 0 instead the difference)

I try something like this:

```
suc :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Int -> (Int,Int,Int) -> Bool
suc (a1, a2, a3) c (d1, d2, d3) = ?????
    where diff1 = if (d1 > a1) then d1-a1       
          diff2 = if (d2 > a2) then d2-a2
          diff3 = if (d3 > a3) then d3-a3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
suc :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Int -> (Int,Int,Int) -> Bool
suc (a1, a2, a3) c (d1, d2, d3) = 
    ((if a1> d1 then 0 else d1-a1) + (if a2> d2 then 0 else d2-a2) + (if a3>d3 then 0 else d3-a3) > c )
```

Or alternatively

```
suc :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Int -> (Int,Int,Int) -> Bool
suc (a1, a2, a3) c (d1, d2, d3) = 
    max 0 (d1-a1) + max 0 (d2-a2) + max 0 (d3-a3) > c
```

Comment: instead of the if's you could try `max 0 (d-a)`

Comment: Great it works, I've only changed >c to <= c, now it's exactly what I want. Thanks a lot

Comment: It is possible to pull apart further: `suc (a1, a2, a3) c (d1, d2, d3) = (> c) . sum . map (max 0) $ zipWith (-) [d1, d2, d3] [a1, a2, a3]`

Comment: @JonPurdy You're definitely right it would work, and it would be a correct way to do for bigger data sets, but personally in this case I would prefer the way used in the answer, as the code is much more readable and not much longer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Because in Haskell, `else` is not a optional part of an `if` expression, so you need to define `diff1` as `diff1 = if d1 > a1 then d1 - a1 else 0`. Other two are similar.
2. Notes that `>` returns a `Bool` value, so you could just sum these three differences up and compare it with `c`, and use it as your condition.

---

There are several ways to define this function:

```
suc1 (a1, a2, a3) c (d1, d2, d3) = diff1 + diff2 + diff3 <= c
    where diff1 = if d1 > a1 then d1 - a1 else 0
          diff2 = if d2 > a2 then d2 - a2 else 0
          diff3 = if d3 > a3 then d3 - a3 else 0

suc2 (a1, a2, a3) c (d1, d2, d3) = sum diffs <= c
    where diff1 = max (d1-a1) 0
          diff2 = max (d2-a2) 0
          diff3 = max (d3-a3) 0
          diffs = [diff1, diff2, diff3]

suc3 (a1, a2, a3) c (d1, d2, d3) = sum (zipWith diff as ds) <= c
    where diff a d = max (d-a) 0
          as = [a1, a2, a3]
          ds = [d1, d2, d3]
```

Comment: Nice! Of course, the third alternative would be much shorter if the arguments were already given as lists, as they maybe should.